# Why my function-based index is not used?

Tags: index, oracle-11g-r2, index-tuning, functions

I have a table `EVENT` with a column `DATE_RECEIVED` (the type of this column is `DATE`):

```
CREATE TABLE "EVENT"
   ("EVENT_ID" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
[...]
   "DATE_RECEIVED" DATE, 
[...]
);
```

I also create a function-based index on `DATE_RECEIVED`:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_EVENT_TRUC_DATE_RECEIVED ON EVENT(TRUNC("DATE_RECEIVED"));
```

But this index is not used. When I run the following request, I got a TABLE ACCESS FULL:

```
SELECT * FROM event
WHERE trunc(date_received) = TO_DATE('30/05/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

In the plan table, I get:

```
----------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
| Id  | Operation         | Name |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CORE |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
----------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("DATE_RECEIVED"))=TO_DATE('                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
              2016-05-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

Note                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   - rule based optimizer used (consider using cbo)
```

I found that `INTERNAL_FUNCTION` means there is an implicit conversion. But I don't know why because `TRUNC` accept `DATE` type.

What can I do to use my index?

Comment: Please tag the question with the appropriate database and version.  It looks like Oracle to me, but I don't know enough about the other databases to make that determination.  If it is Oracle, you really should be using the CBO as the RBO was de-supported as of Oracle 11g (it was deprecated long before that, since Oracle 7.1 I believe).

Comment: @KrisJohnston You're right, I totally forgot to mention it's Oracle 11gr2.

Comment: @JSapkota It cannot work because `date_received` is an Oracle `date` type. Indeed, Oracle `date` type manages hours, minutes and seconds so your query is equivalent to this one: `SELECT * FROM event WHERE date_received = TO_DATE('12/05/2017 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');` that is not what I want: I need all the events of the day.
However, I don't have any index on `date_received` column.

Comment: Oh, as suggested by Kris, consider using CBO instead of RBO.

Comment: Cost-based optimizer is using the index to access the table for the same query, example is here:http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1cad4b45afb1ae7816dc67a28a424968

Comment: @JSapkota Indeed, when I use CBO, my index is really used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JSapkota said in the comments, I need to use CBO instead of RBO. To do it, I need to gather stats on the `EVENT` table:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('USER', 'EVENT');
```

This time, the index is used:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                              | 20000 |    25M|  2166   (1)| 00:00:26 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EVENT                        | 20000 |    25M|  2166   (1)| 00:00:26 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_EVENT_TRUC_DATE_RECEIVED |  8000 |       |    88   (0)| 00:00:02 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```